# Multiselect without showing result on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use multiselect JS with php to get more than one selection of my form select.

Impossible for me not to show the selection' results on the select tags.
At least, if It's possible to show just the number of sélection(s) , it would be nice.
Thanks.

Sorry by impossible for to enter my code for the moment ! (seem not working)

```
<label for="showroom">Type/products* :</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="materials" name="materials" multiple="multiple">
    <?php while($prod=mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodQ)): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $prod['choc_id']; ?>"><?php echo $prod['choc_nom']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#materials').multiselect();

            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Show your code so we can help you :)

Comment: don't know .... I 've tried to paste my code as always but not working. No time to play and re make always and always. Perhaps someone can understand what I mean. Otherwise, I try again in one hours hoping it will work.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Are options generated correctly by PHP? Can you see `<option>` tags inside of your `<select>` when viewing page source? (use `Ctrl+U` button). Also, do you have any errors in console? (use `Ctrl+Shift+J`). Finally, can you provide a screenshot of how does it look and tell how it should?

Comment: yes everything go well with the select.... and datas Inside. Just something wrong with the mulltiselect js...  the result (I can see my selection in the label and I don't  want). I think is just an ajustment to code with the js but I'm not champion in js....